# Is there a way to print out output in a pyramid view callable?

Tags: python, view, pyramid

I am new to python and pyramid and I am trying to figure out a way to print out some object values that I am using in a view callable to get a better idea of how things are working. More specifically, I am wanting to see what is coming out of a sqlalchemy query.

```
DBSession.query(User).filter(User.name.like('%'+request.matchdict['search']+'%'))
```

I need to take that query and then look up what Office a user belongs to by the office_id attribute that is part of the User object. I was thinking of looping through the users that come up from that query and doing another query to look up the office information (in the offices table). I need to build a dictionary that includes some User information and some Office information then return it to the browser as json.

Is there a way that I can experiment with different attempts at this while viewing my output without having to rely on the browser. I am more of a front end developer so when I am writing javascript I just view my outputs using console.log(output).

console.log(output) is to JavaScript

as

????? is to Python (specifically pyramid view callable)

Hope the question is not dumb. Just trying to learn. Appreciate anyones help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good reason to experiment with `pshell`, Pyramid's interactive python interpreter. From within pshell you can tinker with things on the command-line and see what they will do before adding them to your application.

http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.4-branch/narr/commandline.html#the-interactive-shell

Of course, you can always use "print" and things will show up in the console. SQLAlchemy also has the `sqlalchemy.echo` ini option that you can turn on to see all queries. And finally, it sounds like you just need to do a join but maybe aren't familiar with how to write complex database queries, so I'd suggest you look into that before resorting to writing separate queries. Likely a single query can return you what you need.